# Bash - changing line and putting '_' before numbers and after

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, cut

My second question in Bash-
I have such line

```
New York 17 Hello 1246873 548
```

and I would like to get this :

```
New York_17_Hello_1246873_548_
```

I can also have

```
Hello_17_New York_123456_54_
```

* dont care if the final underscore exists or not,
however,we must use array to solve this so I wanted to cut it and store it into an array but got stuck in the middle
any solutions?:)

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash, with no external tools (`sed`, `awk`, etc) required:

```
s='New York 17 Hello 1246873 548'

# replace any space immediately before a digit with an underscore
while [[ $s =~ (^|[[:space:]])[[:digit:]] ]]; do
  s=${s//$BASH_REMATCH/_${BASH_REMATCH:1}}
done

# replace any space immediately after a digit with an underscore
while [[ $s =~ [[:digit:]]([[:space:]]|$) ]]; do
  s=${s//$BASH_REMATCH/${BASH_REMATCH:0:1}_}
done
```

...emits:

```
New York_17_Hello_12468_73_548_
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple native bash solution is to use parameter expansion :

```
${variable// /_}
```

This will replace every occurrence of   in `variable` by `_`.

For example,

```
test="New York 17 Hello 1246873 548"
echo ${test// /_}
```

will output `New_York_17_Hello_1246873_548`.

However, you requested an array-based solution. Note that this is especially convoluted, as `bash` is great to handle strings but not so much with arrays.

The first step would be to split the text into an array of words. This can be easily done as the text is space separated, space being the default separator for parameters :

```
testArray=($test)
echo ${testArray[0]}
```

The echo here will output `New`.

Now we need to join it back with `_`. Since you said you didn't care about a trailing `_`, you can just print each part of the array followed by a `_` :

```
for part in ${testArray[@]}; do
    echo -n "${part}_"
done
```

Here `${testArray[@]}` explodes the array, which `for` can then loop over, and `echo -n` outputs text without following it with a line feed. We need to enclose the `$part` variable into `${...}` or else the underscore would be understood by bash as part of the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed:

```
p='New York 17 Hello 1246873 548'
sed -E 's/ *([0-9]+) */_\1_/g; s/_(_[0-9]+)/\1/g' <<< "$p"

New York_17_Hello_1246873_548_
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
echo 'New York 17 Hello 1246873 548
Hello 17 New York 123456 54' \
    | perl -lnwe ' @f = split /(?<=[0-9]) | (?=[0-9])/;
                   print join("_", @f), $f[-1] =~ /[0-9]$/ ? "_" : "";
                 '
```

It would be much easier without the final underscore.